# Why won't my sql database update on submit?

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

I have the following form with a submit button:

```
<form id ="easytohard" class = "classtest" action="framework.php" method="POST">

<div class="test" style="display:none">

<input type="submit" name="easytohardbutton">

</div>
</form>
```

Note: I do have `session_start();` elsewhere above this script within the code.

When I press the 'submit' button, I want it to update a column titled "FUNCTIONSLEVEL" in a database titled "answers." To do so, I tried using the following code:

```
<?php  
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if(isset($_POST['easytohardbutton'])){

  $res6 = $db->query("SELECT FUNCTIONSLEVEL FROM answers WHERE id=$id");
  $data6 = $res6->fetch_array();

    if($data6['FUNCTIONSLEVEL']==0)$db->query("UPDATE answers SET FUNCTIONSLEVEL = 1 WHERE id=$id");

}  
?>
```

Below is a screenshot of the sql so you can see that there shouldn't be any issues with my database references.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: thats weird, the whole div that has the button has `display: none` inline css. you can't even click the button at all == no update. lol

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors? If no, are you *looking* for errors (error-reporting, for PHP and the used SQL API)?

Comment: @Ghost That's related to a different part of the code. It appears after another condition is met.

Comment: @Qirel To my chagrin, I don't know how to look for errors. (complete novice, obviously ha)

Comment: Bamar gave you a solid answer, and that code does work (replaces your entire if-block). For future reference, [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is for errors in PHP, [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for errors in MySQLi.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's a solid answer, but unfortunately it does not solve my issue :(

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use two separate queries, you can do it all in SQL. And you should use a prepared query rather than string substitution.

```
if(isset($_POST['easytohardbutton'])){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE answers SET functionslevel = 1
                          WHERE id = ? AND functionslevel = 0") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. (I did replace the id = ? with id = $id.) What does the "i" stand for after bind_param? Maybe I should have changed that?

Comment: @user3666954 You're not supposed to change anything. It should look like that, that's how prepared statements work. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @user3666954 Read the documentation. The first argument specifies the types of the parameters: `i` for integer, `s` for string.

Comment: well, I first tried it as you provided it to me and that didn't work either.

Comment: Add the `or die` code that I just added to my answer, in case there's an error in the query.

Comment: I copied exactly what you have (including the `or die` portion) and it's still not updating. The $id is correct, because the other portions of my code involving `$id = $_SESSION['id'];` do update the database correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executing? Add `echo "updating id = $id";` to it to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't updating because you haven't started your session. You need to put:

```
session_start();
```

on **every page** that you want to use sessions on. So your `$id` variable essentially equals nothing.

Not to mention it looks like you're using PDO/Mysqli, why aren't you using Prepared Statements with it? Along with the issue that you're assigning instead of comparing:

```
if($data6['FUNCTIONSLEVEL']=0)...
```

Should be:

```
if($data6['FUNCTIONSLEVEL']==0)....
```

Comment: I had session_start(); above that elsewhere in the code. (Sry - forgot to include here.) I changed the = to a == and it still didn't update.

Comment: @user3666954 can you do a `print_r($data6);` before the `if` and let me know what it shows.

Comment: Just noticed another typo in the code: `SET FUNCTIONSLEVEL == 1`. That should just be `=`.

Comment: Hm, wait I just changed that because I thought Darren said in the comment to which we're replying that it has to be  ==.

Comment: `==` is a comparison operator (`if ($a == $b` would check if they are equal), `=` is an assignment operator (`if ($a = $b)` would set the variable `$a` equal to `$b`).

Comment: @user3666954 your `if` statement, not your query. Look at what i said in the answer

Comment: @user3666954 In SQL, `=` is used for both assignment and comparison, depending on the context.

Comment: Got it :) Either way, I tried both combinations and it didn't solve the issue.